# What does "powerful commodities" mean in The Markenmore Mystery?

Tags: meaning, the-markenmore-mystery, j-s-fletcher

In *[The Markenmore Mystery](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/59818/59818-h/59818-h.htm#toc1)* (1922) by J. S. Fletcher, two men were talking about that whoever commits a crime by chance doesn't have a reason to incriminate himself

> “Ain’t no ’casion as I knows on for any man or woman to go for to accuse theirselves o’ terrible doings. Wouldn’t be a common-sense thing for anybody as that happened to come for’rard and say as they done it! Ain’t Christian conduck for anybody to walk into a trap wi’ his eyes open, I do reckon.”
>
> “’Tis very true!” assented another wiseacre. “Noo—I don’t count as how any **well-disposed**, law abiding citizen have any call to ’criminate his-self—’tis agin religion and nature, which is **powerful commodities**. Noo!—I reckon that if Mistress Braxfield done this, accidental like, wi’ that pistol what Bill Carver refer to, she say to herself ‘Well,’ she say, ‘this here is a sad misfortune to happen to me, but I ain’t no call to tell about it,’ she say, and then, of course, she say nothing. That be the way of it—common-sense, like. And we all knows that accidents does happen to the meekest of us!”

I have two questions here:

1. What does "powerful commodities" mean here?
2. I found that "well-disposed" may mean "friendly, helpful or sympathetic", so what is the connection between this particular adjective and this attitude? I can, for example, understand the connection between "having a common sense" and this attitude, but I can't get that connection that I ask about. Can it mean "behave well in different situations"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. One of the definitions of **commodity** is "something useful or valued." See meaning 2a at [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commodity), where the example given is:

   > that valuable *commodity*, patience.

   Even more than patience, **religion** and **nature** are significant forces highly valued in society, so they are **powerful commodities**. It is worth mentioning that **agin ... nature** here refers to human nature rather than flora, fauna, and the landscape.
2. *Disposition* means "temperamental makeup"—see definition 1b at [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disposition). The friendliness and helpfulness of **well-disposed** people is attributed to psychological and emotional soundness. Someone who is well-disposed would not, therefore, voluntarily incriminate themselves, because they'd have too much common sense to do so.